# Short story about man from an idealistic future who grows a horn on his forehead

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The man wakes up every morning and looks at his wrist-watch screen that tells him that he feels fine when he doesn't. A lump begins to show on his forehead that grows daily and eventually becomes like a unicorns horn. He eventually breaks away from his society and I think even meets a woman with the same condition so has a happy ending... I think. I might be confusing the ending, it's been a while. I read it maybe 30yrs ago but I'm fairly sure it was written in the 50's for some reason. Cheers

Comment: I think this was in one of the Continuum book series, edited  by Roger Elwood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found someone else looking for it: https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/2029851-solved-man-slowly-transforms-into-unicorn-you-are-ok-you-are-not-ok

Solved as "Mythological Beast" by Stephen Donaldson of Thomas Covenant fame.  Link in comments below...

Not much of a summary, but what I found ([from Best of Stephen Donaldson](http://www.sfcrowsnest.com/articles/books/2012/The-Best-Of-Stephen-R-Donaldson-16684.php))

> I will skip lightly over ‘Mythological Beast’ which was a slight story about a man in a safe, secure future world turning into a unicorn. Deftly handled but basically silly.

I rememembered reading it and couldn't recall the circumstances, but I know I read [Daughter of Regals](https://smile.amazon.com/Daughter-Regals-Other-Stephen-Donaldson/dp/0425256952/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1490385079&sr=8-1&keywords=daughter%20of%20regals) which contains it.

Comment: Google Books has the story at https://books.google.com/books?id=MZp0CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT88&lpg=PT88&dq=%22Mythological+Beast%22+by+Stephen+Donaldson&source=bl&ots=l752ANYVU7&sig=8UqR-34Hj0Py-ul5XqDWBrPdMbM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi90JaX9O_SAhXMxYMKHR3FBU0Q6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22Mythological%20Beast%22%20by%20Stephen%20Donaldson&f=false